# A macro defined with brackets and without brackets - redefinition error

Tags: c++, c, macros

What is the difference between `#define WITHBRACKETS (1)` and `#define WITHBRACKETS 1`?

I have macros defined in two places with same name (I know it's a bad thing that likely results in a redefinition warning) but they are defined differently.

So when I compile the code base, why does the compiler say, `#define WITHBRACKETS (1)` is an incompatible redefinition of `#define WITHBRACKETS 1`?

Comment: one has brackets and the other one doesnt...

Comment: Both examples shown seem pretty useless to me.

Comment: macros are not about values if thats what causes your confusion, so in the world of macros `1` is not the same as `(1)`. Macros are about text

Comment: Do note that without parentheses, both cases such as `SQUARE(1+2)` and cases of `DOUBLE(2) * 3` can cause errors, if the first expands to `1+2 * 1+2` or the second expands to `2 + 2 * 3`. In addition, even simple ones can potentially cause different behaviour. For example, `#define FOO (1)` blocks users from appending a user-defined literal.

Comment: @StoryTeller That'll teach me to read the whole question before suggesting a dupe ;)  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The preprocessor complains it's an incompatible redefinition because it is!

A macro is a token that the preprocessor replaces by a sequence of 0 or more other tokens whenever it encounters it.

`#define WITHBRACKETS 1` Will define a token that will be replaced by a **single** other token.

`#define WITHBRACKETS (1)` Will define a token to be replaced by **three** other tokens.

Those aren't compatible things. The preprocessor doesn't know or care that their semantic meaning in the source is the same. All it cares about is the sequence of tokens.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good idea to add the brackets sometimes, for example with something like this :

`#define EXAMPLE (1 + 2)`

the brackets here can be useful against operator priority errors ...
In your example, the compiler says there is a redefinition because the preprocessor does not know that `1` is the same as `(1)`, it just sees that there are two different sequences of characters.

Answer (score 1):

In simple words: Macros are merely about textual replacement.

If you have those two macros:

```
#define WITH (1)
#define WITHOUT 1
```

Then this:

```
foo( WITHOUT );
foo WITH ;
```

will expand to

```
foo( 1 );
foo (1);
```

So the two defines are indeed different. You can use the `-E` flag on gcc to see the output after the preprocessing.

PS: Dont use macros (if you dont need to ;).

Comment: Fantastic point about `foo WITH ;` (Though a developer who is caught writing code like that should be sent to a "re-education" camp).

Comment: @StoryTeller I felt a bit of pain while writing it, but I think it demonstrates quite nicely what macros can do to otherwise readable code